# Post preview mechanism architecture

Tags: posts, previews

I'm trying to find how WordPress is dealing with preview posts before publish.

I'm entering the edit mode of a post that I want to edit, changing some stuff, pressing preview, and getting the preview shown with changes.

My questions are:

1. Is the preview post rendered and routed the same way as the live
   one?
2. If yes, does WordPress save another entity of that post in the database which looks just as the original post but with changes, and that entity is rendered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if you hit just one button for "Preview" it may ends in 2 different "routes".

The one is something like

```
http://example.com/postname/?preview=true
```

The second is something like:

```
http://example.com/postname/?preview_id=152&preview_nonce=xxx&preview=true
```

so the first contains `preview` query argument, the second contains

- `preview_id`
- `preview_nonce`
- `preview`

query arguments.

`preview` query argument tells WordPress to allow visualization of non-published posts to users with proper capabilitites.

If you have a post saved as "draft", and you are logged in, you can view it in front-end just like it was published, simply adding `?preview=true` to the post url.

The second kind of url are *attached* to preview button via javascript when a post autosave runs.

An autosave stores the post as it is (so including any change) in posts table, but replacing actual post type with type "revision".

Find more information [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions).

Autosave runs at regular intervals on backend, but also runs when you click the "Preview" button, in this way in the preview screen you always see last changes.

This is what happen:

1. You click "Preview" button
2. WordPress stores current post in posts table as revision
3. A browser page with post url and `preview_id`, `preview_nonce` and `preview` query argument is opened
4. WordPress pulls the post object from posts table
5. Because of `preview` query argument is present, WordPress

   1. Verifies current user is logged and has proper capabilities
   2. Verifies nonce
   3. If previous checks pass, WordPress pulls last post revision from database, ensuring that revision post name and post author matches post name and post author of post object pulled at point `4`
   4. If a valid revision is found, the post object pulled at point `4` is replaced with revision post object

Besides of that, a preview is handled the same way of normal front-end request for a sigular post, but once the post object used to display the page is taken from revision database row, you see the last, even not saved, post changes.

Comment: Thank you very much! A few questions: in point 2 when you say stores as a revision, that means wp creates a new raw, with same parameters as it would if I published the post, but only the type is revision? If so than every time I click the preview button, is a new instance is created or is it overriding the previous preview instance?

Comment: Everytime the preview button is clicked, WP adds a row to database, that inherits columns from the row for the "regular" post, but has post type set as "revision" and last changes done in the post edit screen. In the preview screen, the `$post` instance is then replaced using data from that revision db row. The original post db row is not touched during preview, but it is only updated when you hit "save" button. Note that old revisions db rows are deleted by WP at regular intervals using [WP cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions). @DimaGimburg

Comment: When I click 'Preview Changes' it alternates between `?preview=true` and the longer version with `preview_id`, etc. So, if I'm on the edit screen, and click 'Preview' 3 times, the first time will be with `?preview=true`, the second time will load `?preview_id=152&preview_non...`, then the third time it's back to `?preview=true`, and so on and so forth, alternating back and forth between URLs with each click. Why is that? Is there any way to make it only ever load with the second, longer URL?